# TypeScript Array Union

Tags: arrays, typescript, union

I am learning about Typescript union. I assigned an array with type **number[] | string[]**. But When I am pushing any string or number in it. Then I am getting an error " *Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'* ".

```
let arr1: string[] | number[] = [];
let arr2: (string | number)[] = [];
let arr3: Array<number | string> = [];

arr1.push(21);
//Error for above push


arr2.push(1);
arr2.push("John Wick");
arr3.push(2);
arr3.push("John Wick");
```

Here I want to make **arr1**  to be either **number** or **string** array.

Can someone please help me understand what is happening here.

Is it possible because of union? Cause when I am assigning a new array, then there is no problem. It's only in the case of **.push()**

```
let arr1: string[] | number[] = [];
let arr2: (string | number)[] = [];
let arr3: Array<number | string> = [];

arr1 = ["John", "Wick"];
arr1 = [0, 1, 2];
//No Error here


let number: string | number = "true";
number = 21;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please make sure not to add images of codes and error messages, as we are unable to debug these. [Edit] your message by adding any relevant codes and a [mcve].

Comment: Could you please provide a code example of what you do exactly.

Comment: @node_modules I am sorry for inconvenience. I have edited the question and added the code in it.

Comment: @JSEvgeny  I am sorry for inconvenience. I have edited the question and added the code in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ...

```
   let arr1: string[] | number[] = [];
```

... you are basically saying: There is an array `arr1` which can either be of type `string[]` or `number[]`. At the same time you are assigning an array without any type, so the compiler will not actually know if `arr1` is a of type `string[]` or `number[]`. As soon as you assign values to the `arr1` where the compiler knows the type, it can also correctly check the type when invoking the `push` operation.

Comment: Got it, so in order to change the type (from number to string), I must re-assign the array cause .push() won't work in that case. right?

Comment: Yes. The `[]` does not give `arr1` an actual type. If you assign `["hi"]`, then `arr1` will be a `string[]` going forward. If you assign a `[1,2,3]`, it will be a `number[]` going forward.